# Why python file in virtual environment is carrying the same installation date after deleting the previous one?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, interpreter

I'm deleting the virtual environment and creating it again and again but in **bin**, the python and python3 file is not recreating. It's showing the installation time of those 2 files are the same as the first time it was installed.
why is this happening? as I'm deleting it completely but again those 2 files carry the same installation time.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files have been copied from the base Python installation and carries the modification time from there.

The files' modification times shouldn't cause any "problems in selecting interpreters".

Comment: it was pulled from a Github repo. So, if I delete the virtual environment, and again creating another virtual environment then why those 2 files are showing at the same time. shouldn't it be updated?

Comment: do you have any solution on this?

Comment: What was pulled from GitHub? No, they're not recreated, because you create the virtualenv using your system's Python, e.g. `python -m venv ...`, and that's where you get the Python from.